# MATLAB Create surface plot of function for all X, Y pairs

Tags: matlab

I have a custom function called `dissmeasure` that outputs a scalar from an input vector of frequencies. Another function called `music.tone2freq` converts integers numbers to frequencies.

My objective is to create a surface plot of `dissmeasure` for all pairs of x,y integers where X and Y equal `[0:1:11]`.

It should look something like this (this is `mesh(X,Y, ones(12,12) )` ): 
[image: sample]

Following from the [mesh docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html), what I have tried is doing:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:1:12)
Z = dissmeasure(music.tone2freq([X., Y.]))
```

But I get `Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.`.

```
Z = dissmeasure(music.tone2freq([X(:), Y(:)]))
```

But `[X(:), Y(:)]` doesn't seem to have the correct size. Also my function that accepts a vector returns one scalar for that whole input. What I need is multiple returns.

Note that both `dissmeasure(music.tone2freq([X(:), Y(:)]))` and `dissmeasure(music.tone2freq([X, Y]))` work, but the result from `dissmeasure` is a single scalar number, not a matrix of the result of this function for each x,y pair.

Any help? Thank you

**tone2freq.m**

```
function f = tone2freq(T)
% MUSIC.TONE2FREQ converts a musical semitone to a frequency.
%    F = MUSIC.TONE2FREQ(T) converts the musical semitones in T to frequencies.
%
%    Example
%       f = music.tone2freq(0:2);  % returns [261.63  277.19  293.67]
%
%    See also music.tone2interval, music.tone2note, music.freq2tone.

%    Author: E. Johnson
%    Copyright 2010 The MathWorks, Inc.


fC4 = 261.625565300599;  % Middle C (C4) is 261.63 Hz

f = fC4 .* 2 .^ (T / 12);
```

**dissmeasure.m:**

```
% calculate dissonace
% input param fvec - list of frequencies
% input param amp  - list of amplitudes
% output is sum of dissonances of each pair of partials (scalar)
function d = dissmeasure(fvec, amp)
  if ~exist('amp','var')
    amp = ones(size(fvec));
  end 

  Xstar = 0.24;   % place with maximum dissonance

  S1 = 0.0207;    % to fit frequency dependend curves
  S2 = 18.96;     % so max. dissonance occures at 1/4 critical bandwidth

  C1 = 5; 
  C2 = -5;

  B1 = -3.51;     % derived from model of Levelt & Plomp
  B2 = -5.75; 

  N = length(fvec);

  [fvec, idx_list] = sort(fvec);  % sort partial frequencies ascending
  amp = amp(idx_list);            % rearrange amplitude values
  %amp = loudness(amp);

  D = 0;

  for i=2:N
    Fmin = fvec(1 : N-i+1);       % get slice as list of Fmin
    S = Xstar./(S1*Fmin+S2);      % calc list of s-scalings with list of Fmin

    % treat vector as tail and head ...
    Fdif = fvec(i:N) - fvec(1:N-i+1);   % build element wise difference
    a = min(amp(i:N), amp(1:N-i+1));    % select element wise a minimum
    Dnew = a .* (C1*exp(B1*S.*Fdif) + C2*exp(B2*S.*Fdif));

    D = D + sum(Dnew);              % sum up last D and vector elements 
  end

  d=D;
```

Comment: What are the `.`s for? e.g. `[X., Y.]`? Also your error is because you have an extra `)` in this line `Z = myfunc([X(:), Y(:)]))`. Lastly, you need to post the code for `myfunc`...

Comment: If `Z = myfunc([X(:), Y(:)]))` does not work, there is probably something wrong with your function. Please add the code to your question.

Comment: As it is currently written, there is an extra `)` at the end of your statement...it should read `Z = myfun([X(:), Y(:)])`

Comment: I added the function sources and more information including a sample mesh of what I'm after

Comment: Note that the dots in `[X., Y.]` are just because I just thought that was the notation for "each individually"

Comment: The dot in `.*` or `.^`  and some other operators indicates element-wise operations.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `dissmeasure` does not support vectorized operations, which means that for inputs of size N the function is evaluated for each element and an output of size N is returned.

Instead your function returns the summarized dissonance.

```
%assuming you have X and Y already converted
Z=X*0 % initialize Z of same size
for ix = 1:numel(X)
    Z(ix)=dissmeasure(X(ix),Y(ix));
end
```

Comment: Can you tell me what do I need to do to achieve what I'm after ?

Comment: Note that this is fine. I WANT the dissmeasure function to aggregate. What I need now is to evaluate it for all the x,y pairs separately

Comment: Use a loop and call it for each pair individually.

Comment: Could you post a bit of code on how to achieve this? Would you recommend adjusting the dissmeasure function so it works with vectors or using a loop?